# Error when i send email from my hosted laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, email, two-step-verification

When I send an email from my local Laravel 5.8 project it's send fine but when I upload the project code in host and I try to send an email using the Laravel project it gives me this error.

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "mygmail@gmail.com" using 2 possible authenticators.
Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data\r\n".
Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data\r\n\
```

This is the content of my .env mail configurations

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='The App Password Generator From Gmail (16 digits)'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mygmail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: The error is quite clear, nevertheless, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit yours accordingly. Also, `smtp.googlemail.com` seems incorrect to me, should it be `smtp.gmail.com`. I also highly doubt that `mygmail@gmail.com` is your actual email, but could be ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same configurations in the config/mail.php file. I was facing the same problem but then used the same configurations in config/mail.php file and it start working.